# Laravel: how to check if data in datatables is valid or not?

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, yajra-datatable

I am trying to get a data from another table through foreign key, i want to check if that data is valid or not, i mean is it empty or not.

**for example** if the foreing key data is empty, i want to return the **null**.

here is what i tried to get it right but not nothing works fine if the foreign key is empty.

[image]

and here is the relationship between the two tables

```
 public function driver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Driver::class, 'Driver_id');
}
```

**And again i want to clear my point**
i want to check if the foreign key data is empty or not, if empty i want return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the Driver_id is set.

```
$driverName = null;
if(isset($bus->Driver_id) && $bus->driver && $bus->driver->first_name) $driverName = $bus->driver->first_name.' '.$bus->driver->last_name.' '.$bus->driver->third_name;
return $driverName;
```